# make css overlap, z-index not working, rendering in random position

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an icon like this :
[image]

Here is my code :

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .dot {
          height: 500px;
          width: 500px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          display: inline-block;
          border: 10px solid red;
        }
        .square {
          height: 353.55px;
          width: 353.55px;
          background-color: #6a6;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        .triangle {
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          border-left: 50px solid transparent;
          border-right: 50px solid transparent;
          border-bottom: 100px solid blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
</body>
```

But what I'm getting is this :

[image]

**How can I make them overlap ?**
*tried z-index : 1 and 2 and 3*, doesn't work

Comment: Try `position:absolute`

Comment: z-index is not enough, you need to set position and control it using left/top/right/bottom

Comment: Position absolute or relative

Comment: @Rmaxx i didn't mentioned any position before

Comment: you need to define position to make z-index work. The accepted answer uses position absolute also. (And pseudo elements, but i think you can do the same without)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for something like this:

```css
.dot {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 332px;
  width: 332px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid red;
  top: 148px;
  left: 190px;
}
.square {
  height: 235px;
  width: 235px;
  background-color: #6a6;
  position: relative;
}

.square:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 0;
  border-top: solid 110px white;
  border-bottom: solid 110px white;
  border-right: solid 110px white;
  border-left: solid 110px white;
}
.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-left: 358px solid transparent;
  border-right: 358px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 500px solid blue;
  z-index: -1;
}
.triangle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: -340px;
  width: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 480px white;
  border-right: solid 340px transparent;
  border-left: solid 340px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
</div>
<div class="dot">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
maybe this is not exactly what you are looking for, but it might help.

```html
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    
        .wrapper {
          position: relative;  
          height: 500px;
          width: 500px;
          transform: scale(0.25)
        }
        
        .dot {
          height: 500px;
          width: 500px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          display: inline-block;
          border: 10px solid red;
          position: absolute;
          left: 50%;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        
        .square {
          height: 353.55px;
          width: 353.55px;
          background-color: #6a6;
          display: inline-block;
          position: absolute;
          left: 50%;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        
        .triangle {
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          border-left:  51px solid transparent;
          border-right: 51px solid transparent;
          border-bottom: 85px solid blue;
          position: absolute;
          left: 50%;
          top: 16%;
          transform-origin: center;
          transform: translateX(-50%) scale(9);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute positioning and reorder the divs. here is what I did, the sizes are wrong but they are overlapping:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .dot {
          height: 500px;
          width: 500px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          display: inline-block;
          border: 10px solid red;
          position:absolute;
          top: 140px;
          left: 130px;
        }
        .square {
          height: 353.55px;
          width: 353.55px;
          background-color: #6a6;
          display: inline-block;
          position:absolute;
          top: 224px;
          left: 214px;
        }
        .triangle {
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          border-left: 400px solid transparent;
          border-right: 400px solid transparent;
          border-bottom: 800px solid blue;
          position:absolute;
          top:0;
          left:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</body>
```

![Here is the result][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Ztd.png